# How can I get Instagram API Permissions?

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I have the problem in Instagram Permissions that I sent 2 submissions, which got denied... LOL My app needs `public_content` Scope but Instagram approved only my `basic` request. I am wondering whether you may help me to use my app to solve this issue.

Regards: amir

Answer (score 0):

Try using this call of api to get the access code

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=[]&redirect_uri=[]&response_type=code&scope=public_content

Answer (score -1):

Try reading the oficial Instagram developer guide. This links can help you.

link | https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/

link | https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/

In this website you can read about permissions on three main criteria.

**Criteria for Review**

**1. Utility**
The requested permissions must provide a non-automated, authentic, high-quality experience to your user and the larger Instagram community.

**2. Visibility**
Data gained from the permission needs to be tied to a direct use and visibly used within your app. We do not accept permission requests for data that you may decide to use later.

**3. Validity**
The requested permission needs to be tied to a valid use case.

Regards